# Record the name of each value that appears 5 times in 5 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have five columns of book names. I am looking for a formula that will record the name of any book that is in all 5 columns in the 6th column.

Currently I am able to do it for two columns using the below but I am having trouble extending it to multiple columns and setting a minimum threshold on it.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A4,$B$4:$B$329,0)),"",A4)
```

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated

**Data:**

```
A             B             C            D            E

Book 1        Book 1        Book 1       Book 3       Book 1
Book 4        Book 2        Book 2       Book 23      Book 4
Book 6        Book 5        Book 5       Book 14      Book 23
Book 9        Book 22       Book 3       Book 2       Book 17
Book 3        Book 6        Book 7       Book 6       Book 2
Book 7                      Book 27      Book 14      Book 15
Book 2                      Book 6       Book 4       Book 6
Book 23                     Book 13      Book 66      Book 9
                            Book 34      Book 32
                                         Book 17
                                         Book 18
```

**Expected Result:**

```
A             B             C            D            E            Answer

Book 1        Book 1        Book 1       Book 3       Book 1       Book 1
Book 4        Book 2        Book 2       Book 23      Book 4       Book 6
Book 6        Book 5        Book 5       Book 14      Book 23
Book 9        Book 22       Book 3       Book 2       Book 17
Book 3        Book 6        Book 7       Book 6       Book 2
Book 7                      Book 27      Book 14      Book 15
Book 2                      Book 6       Book 4       Book 6
Book 23                     Book 13      Book 66      Book 9
                            Book 34      Book 32
                                         Book 17
                                         Book 18
```

The alternative would be to highlight all values that appear at least 5 times.

Comment: the highlighting option much easier

Comment: I can generate a list of each unique entry in your table and then put the count in the cell beside it, but so far I cant wrap my head around a single formula to generate a unique list where the count is >=5.

Comment: BTW, book1 in your expected answer only appears 4 times.

Answer (score 2):

For a formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$11,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$1:$E$11)/((COUNTIF($A$1:$E$11,$A$1:$E$11)=COLUMNS($A$1:$E$11))*(COLUMN($A$1:$E$11)=1)),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```

[image]

One caveat.  The titles must be unique per column.

Comment: @ForwardEd like this?

Comment: yes, except for the caveat. but yes! and interesting, I was not notified by  the @Forwarded 8(   PS:  if you are ever up for a challenge, find a one cell solution for calculating easter sunday for a year in th 1900-2199 range.  not challenging enough?  Challenge B go for any year!

Comment: @ForwardEd I can't with a formula, but I can with a UDF.

Comment: @ForwardEd here is a formula for Easter on any given year `=IF(WEEKDAY(((INT((DATE(N8,3,20)-39853.4090277778)/29.5305556)+1)*29.5305556)+39853.4090277778)<>1,(((INT((DATE(N8,3,20)-39853.4090277778)/29.5305556)+1)*29.5305556)+39853.4090277778)+7-(WEEKDAY(((INT((DATE(N8,3,20)-39853.4090277778)/29.5305556)+1)*29.5305556)+39853.4090277778))+1,(((INT((DATE(N8,3,20)-39853.4090277778)/29.5305556)+1)*29.5305556)+39853.4090277778))`  Where N8 is the cell in which the year is.

Comment: Talk about challenge accepted!  Gold star for you sir!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Proof of concept]

Select the range of your data and ensure the top left corner of the selection is your active cell.  Then for conditional formatting, select the "Use a formula..." option and enter the following formula in formula bar:

=COUNTIF($A$1:$E$11,A1)>=5

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Select the format button, and select various formatting options that you would like to apply when your condition is true.  In this case the condition is when the entry of a cell occurs 5 or more times within the selected range.

No helper cells were used in this method.

Now the following is not what you asked for but I thought I would include it in case it helped, or helped someone us on the steps to your solution.

[image]

In order to generate the list of unique names I used the following array formula in a single cell in G2:

```
{=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($A$1:$E$11<>"")*(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$A$1:$E$11)=0),ROW($1:$11)*100+COLUMN($A:$E),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""}
```

To generate the {} which is the indication of the array formula hold CTRL and SHIFT when you press ENTER.  This is why array formulas are also known as CSE formulas.  I then copied (do not drag) the cell down as needed.

In the adjacent column H, the number of times the name column F appeared in the range A1:E11 was counted.  In H2 the following formula was used and dragged down:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$E$11,G2)
```

The final touch was adding conditional formatting to change the cells colour.  Using the same technique as above. With the G2:H20 range selected and G2 as the active cell I used the following formula in the conditional formatting window:

```
=$H2>=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast idea:
5 auxiliary columns with formula:= `=if(countif($A:$E;A1)>=5;countif($A:$E;A1);"")`
Conditional format in a:e range with =f1...j11<>"" then highlight in green.

[image]