# Get unique values from matrix

Tags: excel, matrix

I have a Matrix and want unique values from this matrix (see picture below)
The matrix is a top 20 pr week, but I want a list of all that during the past year have made it to the "weekly top 20 list".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($A$1:$E$11<>"")*(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$A$1:$E$11)=0),ROW($1:$11)*100+COLUMN($A:$E),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""
```

place that off in some cell to the right and adjust your address ranges.  With out knowing your column headers and row numbers I cant make the adjustments for you.   $G1:G has to be an empty cell above the column just above the start of the column you are generating of unique name...actually it maybe ok to be a filled with text that is not in your matrix, but I have not tested that.

When you are done press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER  (also known as CSE).  This should cause {} to appear around the formula  placing the {} on your own manually does not work for the formula.  Then copy and paste...do not drag...the cell with the formula down as far as you need to go.  You will have a unique list of names from your matrix.

[image: array formula]

UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT DATA

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|    |     D      |     E      |     F      |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  3 |     6      |     7      |     8      |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  4 | Company 1  | Company 2  | Company 1  |
|  5 | Company 2  | Company 3  | Company 3  |
|  6 | Company 3  | Company 4  | Company 5  |
|  7 | Company 4  | Company 5  | Company 7  |
|  8 | Company 5  | Company 6  | Company 8  |
|  9 | Company 6  | Company 7  | Company 9  |
| 10 | Company 7  | Company 8  | Company 10 |
| 11 | Company 8  | Company 9  | Company 11 |
| 12 | Company 9  | Company 10 | Company 12 |
| 13 | Company 10 | Company 11 | Company 13 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

I placed the formula in J3 with CSE and copied down (not dragged down).  note the address reference changes to so how the formula was modified to suit your data.

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($D$4:$F$13<>"")*(COUNTIF($J$2:J2,$D$4:$F$13)=0),ROW($4:$13)*100+COLUMN($D:$F),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""
```

[image: proof of concept]

not the column selection where I pasted the array formula.  It is longer than the list of names.  When this happen, "" is returned.

Comment: Tried to use your formular - But im not quite sure where what goes do all the 3 areas cover it all, or how should it look ? http://imgur.com/rtP03ie how would it look in this example ? -Thank you :)

Comment: Ok, tell me this, what is the cell address for rank 1 week 6.  Also what is the address of the bottom right corner of your matrix of Company #?  and last but not least what cell would you like your list to start in?

Comment: sorry did not see your edit of the screen shot.  I was also going to suggest you may want to look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102002/record-the-name-of-each-value-that-appears-5-times-in-5-columns/37104448#37104448)

Comment: Holy sweet mother.. it is working - THANK you !! here it is in danish =INDIREKTE(TEKST(MIN(HVIS(($D$4:$F$13<>"")*(TÆL.HVIS($J$2:J2;$D$4:$F$13)=0);RÆKKE($4:$13)*100+KOLONNE($D:$F);7^8));"R0C00");)&""    BTW what is to R0C00 doing ?

Comment: I believe its telling the computer at somepoint that instead of referencing cells like A1 in a letter number index system, it says that its using more of the VBA style and referring to the number of the row and then the number of the column.  R for row, and C for Column.  Its not a common usage, but it has its time and place.